# Looking for a simple wrapper for a dynamic array of string pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I need a simple class to wrap a c style array of pointer strings, namely `char **` 
I need minimal operations on my wrapper including adding elements( const or non const ), iterating, random access and querying size. I started using a std::vector like below but I don't like it for reasons described below 
This is my start

```
struct CstrVector
{
   CstrVector(){}
    char *convertToC(const std::string & str)
    {
        char *c = new char[str.size()+1];
        std::strcpy(c, str.c_str());
        return c; 
    }
    void add( const char* c)
    {
       //??
    }
    void add(const std::string& str )
    {
        data.push_back(convertToC(str));
    }
    void add(const std::string& s, unsigned int pos )
    {
        if( pos < data.size())
        {
            data[pos] = convertToC(s);
        }
    } 
   ~CstrVector()
   {
     for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < data.size() ; i++ )
     {
        delete [] data[i];
     }
   }
   char ** vdata;
  std::vector<char*> data; // I want to replace this with char ** vdata
};
```

Why not use 
 `std::vector<char*>` 
 I don't see a benefit it since I still have to allocate and free the memory outside the container ( std::vector ) anyway
Why not use 
 `std::vector<std:string>` 
 because I want to be able to easily pass the array to a C function that will manipulate / change it contents.

Comment: You don't see a benefit in using `std::vector`? I can see one: you don't have to write it.

Comment: You said `adding elements( const or non const )` but why would you add on a `const` ?

Comment: You don't mention

    std::vector< std::vector <char > >

in your list of choices: this is probably cleaner and more efficient than 

    std::vector<std:string>

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes  I use std::vector all the time but I guess I wonder if it is worth it in this case. The vector does not even manage the memory for me. All I get is iteration and random access.

Comment: @MrLunchtime The nested vector will not have contiguous memory I think

Comment: @MrLunchtime: How can you get a useful `char**` out of that?

Comment: @MrLunchtime: That's a good idea.  You could legally use &v[i][0] as a c-string.  You should make an answer of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using

```
std::vector<std:string>
```

If you want to pass `char` string to c functions you can simply do so using **[string::c_str](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)**

Comment: Unfortunately `string::c_str` is `const`.

Comment: He's not trying to pass a C-string, he's trying to pass an array of C-strings, which is not as easily done. It could be encapsulated in a method that dynamically allocates an array of pointers and sets each of them to the `c_str` result.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: Yup, that's right, that would add a little overhead of copying it in a temp buffer before passing it on ahead.

Comment: @Als C functions cannot write to std::string. May be they can I just don't know how

Comment: @mohan: Ofcourse, they can't, they know nothing about `string` being a type. I am a little confused about your comment here and what you quote in the question.

Comment: +1, The *problem* with `std::string::c_str` is not a problem, you can obtain a non-const pointer as: `&str[0]` in the same way that you obtain a pointer to a `std::vector` buffer. There are different places that claim that this is not safe, well it is not according to the C++03 standard that allows ropes, but it is safe in all C++ implementations that I know of, and it will be safe in C++0x.

Comment: @dribeas  Assuming &str[0] is safe and reliable, would a c function recognize this as an array of string pointers as opposed to an array of characters? I think the later

Answer (score 2):

You could still use the `std::vector<char *>`. The `vector` guarantees to store its contents in a consecutive manner, more precisely in an array. If you want to pass the `char **` array to a C function you just have to pass the address of the first element in the vector:

```
void c_function(char ** data);

std::vector<char *> myvec;
...

c_function(&myvec[0]);
```

Notes:

- You still have to do the memory management for the single `char*`s
- this **only** works for `std::vector<char*>` and **not** for `std::vector<std::string>`!

Answer (score 1):

Would [Boost ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) work for you?

Comment: I am not sure. Is boost::ptr_vector<char> same as std::vector<char*> ?

Comment: @mohan: it is similar, but deletes the objects that the contained pointers point to when it is destructed. More info: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html